# PyGame os.environ SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS does not work

Tags: python, pygame, operating-system

I'm trying to set the position of my window in PyGame, but this method doesn't work for me. It says that it's updated when I print it out, but nothing changes visually.

My code:

```
    import pygame as pg
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import time
import sys
import requests
import os

pg.init()

sc = pg.display.set_mode((1000,750))
try:
    testimg143 = open("Data\\test.txt", "r")
except:
    ud = "ginfo\\"
else:
    ud = ""
    testimg143.close()

#main game loop

gamewindowfullscreen = False

def setgamewindowcenter():
    x = 500
    y = 100
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (x,y)
    print(os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'])

while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if (event.type == pg.KEYUP):
            if (event.key == pg.K_F11):
                if (gamewindowfullscreen == False):
                    sc = pg.display.set_mode((0,0), pg.FULLSCREEN)
                    setgamewindowcenter()
                    gamewindowfullscreen = True
                else:
                    sc = pg.display.set_mode((1000,750))
                    setgamewindowcenter()
                    gamewindowfullscreen = False
                    
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                exit()
```

Comment: as I remeber `SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS` is used only at start and later you can't change it. I'm not sure if you have to set it before `set_mode` or maybe even before `init()`

Comment: I tested it - `SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS` works only if you set it before `pg.init()`. Later it is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With earlier version of Pygame (before 2.0.0), the window position could be change by setting `SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS` and calling [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) (at least at some systems.
This is no longer possible. If you want to change the position of the window you have to reinitialize the [`display`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html) module `pygame.display.quit()` and  `pygame.display.init()`.
In any case `SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS` needs to be set before calling `pygame.display.set_mode()`.

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame as pg
import os

def setgamewindowcenter(x = 500, y = 100):
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (x,y)
    print(os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'])

pg.init()
setgamewindowcenter()
sc = pg.display.set_mode((1000, 750))

gamewindowfullscreen = False
run = True
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pg.K_F11:
                if gamewindowfullscreen == False:
                    sc = pg.display.set_mode((0,0), pg.FULLSCREEN)
                    gamewindowfullscreen = True
                else:
                    pg.display.quit()
                    setgamewindowcenter()
                    pg.display.init()
                    sc = pg.display.set_mode((1000, 750))
                    gamewindowfullscreen = False
                    
pg.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, you can use the C API to move the window via [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos)

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, wintypes, pointer

SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002
SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200
SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001


def move_window_abs(x, y, hwnd=None):
    if hwnd is None:
        hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
    windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER)
```

Together with a helper function to get the exact position:

```
class Rect(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("left", wintypes.LONG),
        ("top", wintypes.LONG),
        ("right", wintypes.LONG),
        ("bottom", wintypes.LONG),
    ]


def get_window_rect(hwnd=None):
    if hwnd is None:
        hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
    r = Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
    windll.user32.GetWindowRect(hwnd, pointer(r))
    return pygame.Rect(r.left, r.top, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top)
```

You can also implement a relative movement function

```
def move_window_rel(dx, dy, hwnd=None):
    if hwnd is None:
        hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
    r = get_window_rect(hwnd)
    windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, r.x + dx, r.y + dy, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER)
```

Note that these functions set the top left corner of the window, not the center.